# JQuery - Unable To Detect Checkbox Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Im currently working on the following JQuery:

```
$('table input[type=checkbox][data-tag=entity-value]').on('change',
    function () {
        var associatedTextboxID = $(this).attr('id').replace('IsAssociated', 'Value');
        var associatedTextbox = $('table input[type=text][id=' + associatedTextboxID + ']');

        if ($(this).prop('checked') && associatedTextbox.val() === "") {
            $(this).prop('border', '1px solid #FF0000');
            $(this).after("<p id='error' class='key-error'>While associated, value is a required field.</p>");
            $('#btnSaveCustomProperty').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#btnSaveCustomPropertyAndContinue').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#error').remove();
            $('#btnSaveCustomProperty').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#btnSaveCustomPropertyAndContinue').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
```

Im trying to execute the block when the user changes the checkbox value. Stepping through the code in the browser reveals that the code does not execute when the checkbox is checked (or not).

Is there a better way to handle the checkbox event?

Comment: Is the checkbox being made dynamically?

Comment: Im using a model (.net) to populate the UI with textboxes and checkboxes based on a selection made in the previous page

Comment: Maybe you should wrap it in `$( document ).ready`. Or your jquery selector is failing...

Comment: you didn't provide enough information. in case those are dynamically created elements, use .live or make sure your jquery version is above 1.7 (since 1.7 the .live has been deprecated and bundled into the .on method)

Comment: Some steps that might be helpful on getting started determining which one is the case: Open your browser console and run this: `$('table input[type=checkbox][data-tag=entity-value]')`. If it returned something, great, your selector is right. If not? Your selector is wrong. If it did return something, put `debugger;` before where you set up the on-change listener. Now run the same selector in your console. Chances are it won't and you either need to wrap it in a $(document).ready(function(){}) like selten98 said, or use a .on() filter argument if the table is dynamically generated.

Comment: JQuery is above 1.7 and my selector does return an object. Also, JQuery is already in $(document).ready(function(){}). I placed a debugger the function block and tried running the selector in the console. This resulted in the same object being returned as before.

Comment: Hm, ok...can you try changing your listener to this: `$('table').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox][data-tag=entity-value]', function(){ ... })`

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I guess I have been looking at this too long because I had [data-tag=entity-value] when it should have been [data-tag=entity-include]. Thanks for your help though!